# Compliling Flash and publishing to iPad

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

Is its currently possible to publish a Flash App to iPad? I see Flash CS5 has the ability to publish to iPhone/iPad - is Apple supporting this and will be able to be sold in the App store. It would be a lot simpler for me to code up my next project in flash as opposed to objective c and cocos2d.

Comment: Look at the FAQ from Adobe, http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Packager_for_iPhone:Developer_FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Adobe FAQ][1] Steve posted certainly clearly says you can compile Air apps for the iOS (the O/S that the iPad runs:

http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Packager_for_iPhone:Developer_FAQ#Which_Flash_Platform_tools_and_technologies_can_be_used_to_build_content_for_iOS.3F

It seems, from what I've read, that you can't run FLASH apps in the *browser* on the iPad, but perhaps you can run AIR apps (FLASH) natively.